# In view check if the user is logged

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to check is the user logged inside my view file, but I keep getting 1 in output:

```
    $user1 = Yii::$app->user->isGuest;
    $user = \Yii::$app->user->isGuest;

echo $user ;
echo $user1 ;

       if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        echo 'User is not logged!';
       }else{
           echo 'User is logged!'; 
       }
```

what always I get as ouput if I logged or not"11 User is not logged!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolve this problem with $session

```
    use yii\web\Session;



    HomeAsset::register($this);

    $session = Yii::$app->session;

    <? if($session['id']){ ?> 
       //user connected
    <? }else{ ?>
        //user is not connected
    <? } ?>
```

Comment: you made my day